# Changing port from 80 to 443 redirects site to index (SSL)

Tags: https, security-certificate, openssl

My setup:

- Apache 2.4.7
- Ubuntu 14.04 w/wordpress
- Host: DigitalOcean

I have figured out what is causing the redirect but I cannot figure out why or how to fix it.

When changing the port from 80 to 443 in `000-default.conf` it directs the site to the index, when put back to 80 the site loads properly but without SSL.

Here is the code of my `000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName prollagen.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/.crt
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: When you say "redirect" - do you actually see an external redirect in the network traffic, or does it simply _serve_ in the index document (ie. an internal rewrite)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to put your configuration into `000-default.conf`.  That file is overwritten when Apache is upgraded.  Instead you should put your configuration into `/etc/apache2/sites-available/prollagen.conf`.   Put the default conf file back to how it was.  You will need two virtual host directives.  One for HTTPS and one for HTTP.   I assume that you want HTTP to redirect to HTTPS.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName prollagen.com
    Redirect permanent / https://prollagen.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName prollagen.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/.crt
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Once this new file is in place enable it and restart the server:

```
sudo a2ensite prollagen && sudo service apache2 restart
```